Making sense of these recipes for removing anodized coatings of aluminum
Background:
There are several black anodized aluminum optical mounting components I'd like to use inside a high vacuum chamber (circa $1 \times 10^{-7}$ Torr or mbar) but several people including the manufacturer have told me that the anodized coatings will have more adsorbed water and other volatile molecules from the atmosphere, (which make pumping down to base pressure take longer) than a bare aluminum surface with its natural, thin, hard, stoichiometric $\ce{Al_2O_3}$ native oxide.
Wondering if there was a way to remove common aluminum anodization coatings by dissolving them, without too much etching or pitting (due to crystallographic directionality) of the underlying aluminum surfaces.
Question:

Removing Anodizing From Aluminum Quickly and Easily. recommends using a commercial cleaner containing sodium hydroxide
Aerospace Metals LLC's How To Remove Anodized Aluminum? contains the following:


Half of the entries on our list are actually found among common household cleaning solutions, such as drain cleaners or oven cleaners. But like we said, simply immersing them or spraying solutions on aluminum components doesn’t always do the trick. It’s very important that you do this in a controlled environment, but we will touch on safety precautions later.

Sodium Hydroxide: Also known as caustic soda or lye ($\ce{NaOH}$), it is the most common method for stripping anodized coating. The concentration of caustic soda is generally 2-10% of 50% liquid caustic soda by volume in water. Depending on the bath concentration and temperature, the anodic coating should strip in a few seconds to a few minutes.
Potassium Hydroxide: Also known as caustic potash ($\ce{KOH}$), this solution acts as a strong base (alkali) and reacts well with acids. It’s commonly found in drain cleaners, along with sodium hydroxide and sulfuric acid. It’s likely that, when applied together, this caustic etch solution will result in a matte appearance on the component.
Acid Etching: This process involves a mixture of chromic acid ($\ce{CrO_3}$) and phosphoric acid ($\ce{‎H_3PO_4}$). The end result will probably look the way it did before the aluminum was anodized, as this chromic phosphoric acid solution is proven to not affect the aluminum surfaces or cause further pitting.
Deoxidizing: To strip the aluminum surface, you can also use a strong de-oxidizer. The aluminum anodized coating is actually a thick oxide layer, and to de-anodize would mean to get rid of this top layer of finishing. Here’s one way to remove the anodic finish from a knife. It also serves as a good guide on how to remove anodized color from aluminum.


I find all of this confusing!
For example,

"Potassium Hydroxide (is) commonly found in drain cleaners, along with sodium hydroxide and sulfuric acid" Is there even such a thing as a "mixture" of potassium hydroxide and sulfuric acid?
Is a "mixture of chromic acid and phosphoric acid" something one would ever want to be near, even with a fume hood and gloves? I'm thinking Erin Brokovich and the dangers of hexavalent chromium.

It seems that oven cleaner or drain cleaner might be the first thing to try (carefully) before graduating to chromic acid.
Will any of these (or all of them) contiue to etch the aluminum metal after clearing the anodization? Are any of them particularly aggressive at that?

May astronomers lend a hand because aluminization of mirrors can be an advantage over silvering (example)? Al2O3 starts to form as soon as Al is exposed to air, anodization artificially increases the thickness of this layer. One way is to trap and cap dye molecules in pits of this honeycomb matrix one could wash away. Anodization with TiO2/coloring by diffraction (Bill Hammack) is a different thing and may be harder to remove; there, black is not a typical result of this technique if applied evenly -

do you describe paint instead? (Thermodynamics is not favorable to have a strong acid (H2SO4) nearby a strong base (NaOH); they want to yield H2O plus Na2SO4 or/and NaHSO4.)

@Buttonwood I wonder if the base + acid in the block quote is just plain wrong. I know there are acid-based drain cleaners (I see hydrochloric acid sold for that where I live) and the more popular bases, but I can't imaging putting both in the same container.

@uhoh, The description is drain is plainly wrong. Key questions (1): How much longer you would have to wait? If it is a day, will that be a big deal? For example, mass spectrometers will also take a day to pump down. (2) How sure are you that the coating is pure anodized Al rather than a mixture of paint+Al2O3. (3) Is there a possibility of keeping the anodized items in a pre-heated vacuum oven at 40-60 degrees with a dessicant like phosphorus pentoxide?

@ACR For pump down time I ten minutes to base pressure is my threshold for pain since I'm opening the chamber frequenlty. Since it's a (big) box full of electron optics and detectors I can't be baking. All the information I've had about anodized surfaces being worse for vacuum has been verbal communication and "wisdom", including from the manufacturer of the parts (in this case Thorlabs engineers). They have a lot of customers with science projects, some in vacuo.

I will actually do a control test first even before thinking about removing the coating. Can you see how much time it takes to reach full vacuum when you do not have anodized parts?

Your first point is probably just poor word choice on the part of the author. When they wrote "potassium hydroxide (is) commonly found in drain cleaners, along with sodium hydroxide and sulfuric acid," they meant "potassium hydroxide, sodium hydroxide, and sulfuric acid are common drain cleaning chemicals."

@anon I see, so it seems I probably I took "along with" more literally than it was meant. Yes, that makes a whole lot of sense. Thanks!

Since aluminum will oxidize rapidly in air, reproducing any removed $\ce{Al2O3}$ layer, consider plating the aluminum parts with a material easier to bake out.

Electroplate nickel onto the aluminum part. As mentioned, removing the tenacious oxide coat is difficult.

Vacuum-deposit titanium. Prolonged sputtering of the aluminum part beforehand can remove the oxide layer.

Vapor deposit $\ce{Ti/TiN}$ onto the aluminum.



Thanks! Plating with metal with a less tenacious oxide is a great idea - it also makes it much easier to ensure the parts are electrically grounded. These days electroless nickel plating is also available for aluminum parts. The problem with anodized coatings on aluminum is that they are both thick (many microns to many tens of microns) and very often quite porous structures. The porosity allows for the incorporation of dyes for coloration but it also provides a big reservoir for adsorbed species like water, which then outgass slowly.

The native stoichiometric $\ce{Al_2O_3}$ oxide that grows quickly on bare aluminum in air is a self-limiting process as it is impermeable to oxygen or anything else. It stops at only about 20 Å. And while the surface has some ability to hang on to water molecules upon pump-down, it's only on the top surface rather than within the volume of of a thick porous anodized layer. I'll note that this is "conventional wisdom" and so far I have not found scientific comparisons, but of all the aluminum vacuum chambers and parts I've seen, they've all been bare - no anodized surfaces, ever.

AFM, SEM and TEM Studies on Porous Anodic Alumina, Ordered porous Materials: Porous Alumina (bibliography), Hard Anodization for Nanoporous Aluminum Oxide, and...

Advances in the Fabrication of Nanoporous Anodic Aluminum Oxide and Its Applications to Sensors: A Review which addresses the variety of chemical processes used to anodize aluminum.
